# using CASE WHEN statements in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, if-statement, ms-access, case

I know how to write `CASE WHEN` statements, but the problem here is translating them to Microsoft Access "language".
I've tried with `IF` statements but it didn't work, I've looked up how to use `CASE WHEN` statements in Access but copying what I found didn't work, I'm clueless..
The following is the code I should translate:

```
SELECT clienti.nome, clienti.cognome

FROM ((clienti

INNER JOIN contiCorrenti ON clienti.ID = contiCorrenti.IDCliente)

INNER JOIN prestiti ON contiCorrenti.IBAN = prestiti.IBAN)

WHERE prestiti.durata < 

              CASE WHEN prestiti.rateizzazione = "mensile"

              THEN 60

              WHEN prestiti.rateizzazione = "annuale"

              THEN 5

              ELSE 0

              END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support case statements. Instead you can use the "immediate if" function (iif) and nest them for multiple conditions:

```
where prestiti.durata < iif (prestiti.rateizzazione = "mensile", 60,
                        iif (prestiti.rateizzazione = "annuale", 5, 0))
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot! Weirdly I didn't come across any website that showed the immediate if function while looking for IF statement

Answer (score 0):

Access does not support CASE in SQL - use `IIf()` or `Choose()` or `Switch()`.

`durata < IIf(rateizzazione = "mensile", 60, IIf(rateizzazione = "annuale", 5, 0))`

or

`durata < Switch(rateizzazione = "mensile, 60, rateizzazione = "annuale", 5, True, 0)`

`Switch()` and `Choose()` are VBA intrinsic function calls but IIf() is SQL so likely performs more efficiently.